# Email approval process using visualforce components and apex class

Tags: salesforce, devops, apex, apex-code, visualforce

I want to Send the an email notification for my discount Approval, so that
the approvers are notified for the Quotes that require approvals.
So now as an approver when I receive a New Sale Quote for discount approval
then I should be able to review and provide approval decisions in the approval notification email
Moreover, Whenever any user who submitted Quote for Approval
WHEN Quote status is updated to 'Denied'
THEN I should receive a Chatter notification
AND I should also receive 'Approver Comments' for Rejection in the notification

Any code or steps to implement these would be helpful...

I have not tried anything yet, since I am confused where to start with.